# Restarting phones getting many notification's

Tags: android

I have simple reminder app. My app's problem is that when I restart my phone or any device, the app starts to throw up many notifications. [This](https://github.com/donnfelker/Task-Reminder/tree/master/src/src/com/dummies/android/taskreminder) is the source code of all Java files. This is OnBootReceiver :

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName();  

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ReminderManager reminderMgr = new ReminderManager(context);

        RemindersDbAdapter dbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(context);
        dbHelper.open();

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllReminders();

        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 

            int rowIdColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
            int dateTimeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME); 

            while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Adding alarm from boot.");
                Log.d(TAG, "Row Id Column Index - " + rowIdColumnIndex);
                Log.d(TAG, "Date Time Column Index - " + dateTimeColumnIndex);

                Long rowId = cursor.getLong(rowIdColumnIndex); 
                String dateTime = cursor.getString(dateTimeColumnIndex); 

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ReminderEditActivity.DATE_TIME_FORMAT); 

                try {
                    java.util.Date date = format.parse(dateTime);
                    cal.setTime(date);

                    reminderMgr.setReminder(rowId, cal); 
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("OnBootReceiver", e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                cursor.moveToNext(); 
            }
            cursor.close() ;    
        }

        dbHelper.close(); 
    }
}
```

And this is WakeReminderIntentService:

```
public abstract class WakeReminderIntentService extends IntentService {
abstract void doReminderWork(Intent intent);

    public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.Static";
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic=null;

    public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
        getLock(context).acquire();
    }

    synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
        if (lockStatic==null) {
            PowerManager mgr=(PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                                                        LOCK_NAME_STATIC);

            lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }
        return(lockStatic);
    }

    public WakeReminderIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            doReminderWork(intent);
        }
        finally {
            //getLock(this).release();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me to cancel notification's after device's restart. In code there is told to schedule notification on specific time, but I am confused why after device's restart I get many notifications from app. Can someone tell me where is the mistake?

**Update:**

OnBootReceiver:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ComponentInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;

public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName();  

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ReminderManager reminderMgr = new ReminderManager(context);

        RemindersDbAdapter dbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(context);
        dbHelper.open();

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllReminders();

        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 

            int rowIdColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
            int dateTimeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_DATE_TIME); 

            while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Adding alarm from boot.");
                Log.d(TAG, "Row Id Column Index - " + rowIdColumnIndex);
                Log.d(TAG, "Date Time Column Index - " + dateTimeColumnIndex);

                Long rowId = cursor.getLong(rowIdColumnIndex); 
                String dateTime = cursor.getString(dateTimeColumnIndex); 

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ReminderEditActivity.DATE_TIME_FORMAT); 

                try {
                    java.util.Date date = format.parse(dateTime);
                    cal.setTime(date);

                    reminderMgr.setReminder(rowId, cal); 
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("OnBootReceiver", e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                cursor.moveToNext(); 
            }
            cursor.close() ;    
        }

        dbHelper.close(); 
    }
}
```

setReminder().method:

```
public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {

    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
```

Comment: Post reminderMgr.setReminder function as well

Comment: Check if your entries returned from the database are past entries? You fetch only those entries whose time is greater than the current time.

Comment: They are not past entries I postes [source code](https://github.com/donnfelker/Task-Reminder/tree/master/src/src/com/dummies/android/taskreminder), if you want you can check that out in there..

Comment: Checked and the problem is in fetchAllReminders. It returns all the entries from the db.

Comment: Add where clause in the query. for eg: where "dateTime" > currentime

Comment: Okei maybe I do not understand can you help me to write what in where?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36129/discussion-between-androidprogrammer-and-tarun)

Comment: In saveState function inside ReminderEditActivity don't save the time as formatted date. Instead just save calendar.getTimeInMillis(). Now in your fetchAllReminder query you can add: return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, "reminder_date_time > " + currentTime.getTimeInMillis(), null, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

Okei I have looked up in your source code and I think you should cancel in your manifest this line :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In `saveState` function in `ReminderEditActivity` class don't save the time as formatted date. Instead just save `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`.

**Example**:

```
private void saveState() {
    long id = mDbHelper.createReminder(title, body, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Now in your fetchAllReminder query you can add:

**Example**:

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, "reminder_date_time > " + currentTime.getTimeInMillis(), null, null, null);
```